# UIImageView image changes with different songs

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

I have a simple media player and I'm trying to make it change the artwork image as the songs change. With the code I have now it will display the artwork when you hit play but when I hit the next button to skip to the next item it stays the same unless you hit another button.

How can I make the UIImageView image change as the song media item changes?

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        createQueue()
    }

    func showArt(){
    coverImageView.image = 
    myMediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.artwork!.image(at: CGSize.init(width: 500, height: 500))
    coverImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    togglePlay(on: sender)
    showArt()
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    back()
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    skip()
    }

}
```

My other functions are as followed:

```
import MediaPlayer

let myMediaPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.systemMusicPlayer

let playDrake = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "Drake", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, comparisonType: MPMediaPredicateComparison.equalTo)

let myFilterSet: Set<MPMediaPropertyPredicate> = [playDrake]

func createQueue() {
        let drakeQuery = MPMediaQuery(filterPredicates: myFilterSet)
        myMediaPlayer.setQueue(with: drakeQuery)
}

func skip() {
        myMediaPlayer.skipToNextItem()
}

func back() {
        if myMediaPlayer.currentPlaybackTime > 0.05 {
            myMediaPlayer.skipToPreviousItem()
        } else if myMediaPlayer.currentPlaybackTime < 0.05 {
            myMediaPlayer.skipToBeginning()
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }


func togglePlay(on: UIButton) {
        if myMediaPlayer.playbackState.rawValue == 2 || myMediaPlayer.playbackState.rawValue == 0 {
            on.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)
            myMediaPlayer.play()
        } else if myMediaPlayer.playbackState.rawValue == 1{
            on.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState.normal)
            myMediaPlayer.pause()
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `showArt()` to your next and back action?

Comment: Where is your `skip` function defined?

Comment: You should show your skip and back() like @kbunarjo questions.

Comment: @MwcsMac I just added my other functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @kbunarjo I just added the other functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I put the showArt() in the other actions, the cover art won't update unless I hit another button. Example: a song is playing I skip to the next song but the cover art won't update until I hit another button.

Comment: Do labels that you are updating with name of item playing? If so how are you updating them?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image asynchronously

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    myMediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.artwork!.image(at: CGSize.init(width: 500, height: 500))
}
```

Comment: I added my supporting functions to the original post. Would I add that code to my View Controller or somewhere else?